# Check if spreadsheet exists

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-api-python-client

I'm developing an application that saves an acquired value to a google spreadsheet. I would like to know if I can do following things via google-spreadsheet API while using python

- Check if a spreadsheet exists with given `name`
- Get a list of spreadsheets while requesting via `name` or `id`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand about `if i can request a list of spreadsheet with name and ID`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Could you show what you tried till now?

Comment: Have you looked into the [`gspread`](https://github.com/burnash/gspread) package? That seems to make it much easier to work with the APIs than the google-spreadsheet API does.

Comment: I have a raspberry that acquire enviroment data and i would like to write in file. the name of ifle is the name of the day with forma dd-mm-yyyy and i want check if the name of spreeedsheet exist or not in the gdrive.... can happen that raspi go down and after minutes go up and it need only to append the data..

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: Can't you just try to write the value(s) and then react upon failure (e.g. spreadsheet does not exist): [EAFP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11360858/3767239)?